# Bluetooth application with react native

Tags: reactjs, bluetooth

Hi i want to write an application in react-native that people in same place can join each other and play a game on bluetooth connection.
The first question is if it is possible with react native?
And second is which documentation can help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see why not, i have used Ionic wich uses Cordova (non native) to create bluetooth connections without problem, bluetooth is a basic feature of phones.

Take a look at this library it may help you or give you a good point of start: https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

Comment: Thanks ! That was all i need